# Is there a GazeManager.Instance.HitInfo.collider but for motioncontroller pointer ray on opaque WMR headsets instead of the same on HoloLens?

Tags: controller, hololens, motion, collider

I would like to know if a built-in Mixed Reality ToolKit way to check whether ray projected from a motion controller visualized by MRTK-Unity when using the controllers with an occluded windows mixed reality headset is raycasting anything exists?

I can check this easily on HoloLens when using a *GazeManager.Instance.HitInfo.collider != null* condition, but since that Gaze Manager pertains to Gaze instead of MotionControllers I can't use that (at least in a way I know) to check if the defaultcursor which is controlled by the motioncontroller projected ray is being projected/raycsted onto something UI or not (and possibly later what)?

*P.S. I saw that MRTK-Unity v2 plans to combine all the pointers (gaze and controllers/hands) in input manager class, but unless I'm wrong that's not available for HoloLens v1, I mean being able to get the pointer for controller since I looked at the InputManager prefab for v1 and couldn't find anything like that...right?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple raycasting could be implemented using [`Physics.Raycast()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) with parameters from a motion controller. The parameters can be taken from [MRTK Input](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/gestures-and-motion-controllers-in-unity). As an example

```
void InteractionManager_InteractionSourcePressed(InteractionSourcePressedEventArgs args)
{
     var interactionSourceState = args.state;
     var sourcePose = interactionSourceState.sourcePose;
     Vector3 sourceGripPosition;
     Quaternion sourceGripRotation;
     if ((sourcePose.TryGetPosition(out sourceGripPosition, InteractionSourceNode.Pointer)) &&
         (sourcePose.TryGetRotation(out sourceGripRotation, InteractionSourceNode.Pointer))) {
         RaycastHit raycastHit;
         if (Physics.Raycast(sourceGripPosition, sourceGripRotation * Vector3.forward, out raycastHit, 10)) {
             var targetObject = raycastHit.collider.gameObject;
             // ...
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I'll keep this in mind, I'm guessing the args.State holds the info on which interaction has occurred so I could try and conclude what is suppose to be the source of Raycast...unfortunatelly it's just that my current version has been made for both HoloLens and now WMR immersive headsets so the code which I'm using for setting firing off the interaction currently would have to be removed or doubled by this...I'm gonna hold of a bit just to see what does v2 have in mind and if hopefully MS will backport it to v1 but it makes me wonder how do they design these APIs so differently?

Comment: P.S. Dumb question but...where exactly is the InteractionManager in the MRTK v1 prefabs...I only got the InputManager when I added the MRTK initially to my project and set it up via the Mixed Realiy Toolkit menu?

Comment: Because a typical human with worn HL has one single head and one single gaze direction. However it would be many hands (including hands of another humans, btw), motion controllers, voices and many many other input options. It means that the spatial input is distributed between multiple sources.

HL2 status you might look [here][https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/milestone/1]

Comment: Namespace: UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input
Types: InteractionManager, InteractionSourceState, InteractionSource, InteractionSourceProperties, InteractionSourceKind, InteractionSourceLocation

Comment: Thank you once again Andrey, I set this as an answer because I'm pretty sure there's not going to be an easy way to do this and still have it work on both classes of devices with v1, and I'm not holding my breath for backporting v2 to run on HL1. I did however try to add the code above and although it builds, I must have not hooked it up properly as in Unity I've mostly been doing stuff via prefabs and some code behind...is there something else I should do beside put `InteractionManager.InteractionSourcePressed += (InteractionSourcePressedEventArgs args) => { *your code here* }` in the Start()

Comment: _And to explain my ranting in the comments for Luis' answer after this..it's more obvious to me now that Microsoft's Academy is just outdated since by looking for namespaces you gave I got this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/gestures-and-motion-controllers-in-unity which gives guidelines that weren't mentioned in the Academy before.._ **I just hope they won't give up on unifying efforts and support for WMR as Thurrot's claiming MS is giving up on UWP.**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the ways of MRTK v1 but in MRTK v2 a more or less straightforward approach for your use case, if I understand it correctly, is to make use of the MRTK pointer attached to the motion controller. That pointer performs a raycast every frame and stores the result in IMixedRealityPointer.Result. You can access the data by either listening to pointer events via IMixedRealityPointerHandler in your script or manually iterating over all pointers via IMixedRealityInputSystem.DetectedInputSources.

Comment: This seems like a way to go for me if MS wanted to use pointers for interaction...regardless if your gaze is one or many pointer devices in 2 hands, they should not have been whole different objects in which some do have HitInfo and others don't...I would respect MS' hodgepodge of v1 if the consistency was there in the Academy if the approach Andrey gave was the one clearly suggested to be the one used, but they went on with pushing for GazeManager even after WMR headsets hit the market, so I'll reluctantly (because of MS not Andrey) award this answer to him but still thank you very much Luis.

Comment: _Since I don't have just enough reputation credits to upvote this one publicly, I'd mark it as an answer too, but it seems that would kill the mark on the other as an answer I'm sorry..._